# Is it possible to print errors to Windows console while running a c++ GUI?

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, windows-console

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible (or plausible) to output specifically error codes to the windows cmd window while executing a gui called from that window. I have a GUI I'm calling from cmd line e.g.  *start GUIprog.exe "arg1"
 "arg2"...* and while that is running, I want to print any errors directly to the cmd window and raise ERRORLEVEL.

Is this possible?

Comment: You can make your GUI program to use CONSOLE subsystem (for debugging) so standard streams will be attached to existing console output.

Comment: For a non-CONSOLE app, try using `AttachConsole()`, `GetStdHandle()`, and `WriteConsole()` to write to the console that spawned the app

Comment: Either make sure to first reset the standard handle(s) that you need to `NULL` before calling `AllocConsole` or `AttachConsole`, or explicitly open "CONIN$" or "CONOUT$". The latter requires generic read-write access, else some console APIs will fail such as `GetConsoleMode`, which is critical since the CRT and other libraries typically use `GetConsoleMode` to check for a console handle, naively assuming it will only fail for a non-console file.

Comment: You can also use `OutputDebugString` to print messages to IDE's output window, while in debug mode.

Comment: Setting `ERRORLEVEL` requires forcing CMD to wait for the GUI process to exit via `start "" /wait GUIprog.exe ...`. Normally CMD doesn't wait for GUI applications run from the interactive command prompt. It determines whether a child is a GUI process by getting the address of the PEB in the child's address space via `NtQueryInformationProcess` and calling `ReadProcessMemory` to read the PEB and check whether its `ImageSubsystem` is `IMAGE_SUBSYSTEM_WINDOWS_GUI` (2).